# Make: Target name in Rule

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

I have created a `Makefile` to generate `pdf` and `html` for a `md` file mentioned while invoking make like `make a.md` should generate `a.pdf` and `a.html`, and should not convert other `md` files present in the directory.

[My make file](https://gist.github.com/Agarwal-Nikhil/e952f631b865886d4bed828ab7b3ce53)

But I am, getting error `Nothing to be done for a.md`

Could you please suggest changes?

Comment: We can no longer read your make file, as the link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `a.md` is already in place, `make` indeed does have nothing further to do. You can either just use for instance `a` as the specified target (which can depend on pdf and html files as prerequisites). Or pass the desired source through a variable and determine your desired target from that.

---

One (the latter) option would be this:

```
EXPORTED= $(SOURCE:%.md=%.html) $(SOURCE:%.md=%.pdf)

%.html : %.md
        pandoc -o $@ $<

%.pdf : %.md
        pandoc -o $@ $<

all: $(EXPORTED)
```

Which you can call with `make SOURCE=a.md`.

---

The other option (former):

```
%.html : %.md
        pandoc -o $@ $<

%.pdf : %.md
        pandoc -o $@ $<

.PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS)
$(MAKECMDGOALS): $(MAKECMDGOALS:%=%.html) $(MAKECMDGOALS:%=%.pdf)
```

Allows you to call `make a`.

---

But to reiterate. You cannot use (existing) source as a target, because make would (as it did) conclude it's done making that target.

---

Except (but I personally do not really like this as it is IMO confusing), if you insisted, you could do a variation on the previous take... but work with `*.md` targets... which you all declare as `.PHONY`. I.e. not real files and always to be considered/remade:

```
%.html : %.md
    echo pandoc -o $@ $<

%.pdf : %.md
    echo pandoc -o $@ $<

.PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS)
$(MAKECMDGOALS): $(MAKECMDGOALS:%.md=%.html) $(MAKECMDGOALS:%.md=%.pdf)
```

Now you could indeed call `make a.md`. I'd still prefer one of the two above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually I wanted to create a general makefile. So, I would like to get the target name as an input (while invoking make). How to pass the desired source through a variable while invoking make?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!! :)

Comment: The solution worked but it could be more elegant if we don't need to pass the variable name with value while invoking make. Can't make just take in the value like `make a.md` and store it in SOURCE Variable?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hope this helps... now there are multiple to chose from. I'd personally probably go for the middle example, first option in the opening paragraph.